# Error: This requires the experimental 'records' language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter

This is for an iOS app with a Flutter Add on

I am trying to use the record feature with Flutter 3.10.3 and  XCode 14.3.1

I have a record

```
typedef StringKeyValue = (String, String);
```

When I run the app for Android all works but when I try run for iOS I get the error

*This requires the experimental 'records' language feature to be enabled.*

```
environment:
  sdk: ^3.0.0
```

I have resorted to using the Tuple library instead of the record feature.

Comment: Is this an old project?  Your pubspec.yaml probably doesn't say ">=3.0.0" and you won't get the 3.0 features without that.  New projects have the right minsdk.

Comment: I included the line from the pubspec yaml above showing it is ^3.0.0

Comment: try "flutter pub upgrade"

Answer (score 3):

Changed

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.3 <3.0.0'
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0'
```